# How can I pass a default MenuItem in Navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working through an Android for beginners book. Despite the fact that it was published in December 2015, there are of course various sections that are now out of date.

I am working on my first app to use a navigation drawer. The original implementation called for the nav items to be displayed using a ListView and Adapter. Switching Fragments was handled by passing integer values to a method:

```
mNavDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     // pass the position of the clicked item to switchFragment
     switchFragment(position);
}
```

However, I found that while this worked, the older way of setting up the nav drawer meant it had display issues, so the drawer appeared under the action bar. After researching the issue, I found that there is a new method of handling navigation drawers in Lollipop. So I have now switched my code over to that method:

```
mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switchFragment(item);
            return true;
       }
});
```

Here is `switchFragment()`:

```
private void switchFragment(MenuItem item){

    Fragment fragment = null;
    String fragmentID = "";

    // handle the choice the user presses in the drawer
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_titles:
            fragmentID = "TITLES";
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("Tag","_NO_TAG");
            fragment = new TitlesFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            break;

        case R.id.nav_tags:
            fragmentID = "TAGS";
            fragment = new TagsFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.nav_capture:
            fragmentID = "CAPTURE";
            fragment = new CaptureFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    // set up a fragment manager and open the fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment, fragmentID).commit();

    // Close the drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mNavigationView);
}
```

The Titles fragment is the default view, and so in a few places in my MainActivity, for example at the end of the `onCreate()` method and on pressing the back button, I originally used a call of `switchFragment(0)` to load this view automatically. However, now that I've switched to the NavigationView version, I naturally can't do that.

I've tried setting and binding a member variable to the default item:

`mDefaultFrag = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.nav_titles);`

(where `nav_titles` is an item in `menu.xml`) and passing that in like this:

`switchFragment(mDefaultFrag)`

but that throws an error:

`Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.view.MenuItem.getItemId()' on a null object reference`

I guess because it's not a View. So how can I grab that default view option to pass to `switchFragment`?

EDIT:

Nav menu items xml (stored in menu > nav.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_titles"

            android:title="Titles" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tags"

            android:title="Tags" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_capture"
            android:title="Capture" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

DrawerLayout in content_main.xml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/nav" /> <!-- The items to display -->
```

OnCreateOptionsMenu:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        mDefaultFrag = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_titles);
        switchFragment(mDefaultFrag);
        return true;
    }
```

After adding this, I've realised that the menu being inflated is the settings menu, not the navigation drawer, so of course it won't find the items in `menu`.

Comment: are you using android studio.?

Comment: Yes, Android Studio, latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Menu` views are created in a different phase than `onCreate()`. Try the below code to grab your menu ID:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(yourMenuID, menu);

    mDefaultFrag = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_titles);
    return true;
}
```

---

Update:

You've got me thinking though...why don't you just replace the fragment with your default one by yourself in `onCreate()`? So just do this in your `onCreate()`:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, new TitlesFragment(), "TITLES")
               .commit();
```

This will give you what you need, a default fragment.

Comment: Using `getItemid()` shows an error in Android Studio - required MenuItem, found int. Removing `getItemId()` causes the same error to be thrown as in my question.

Comment: Look, `menu.findItem(R.id.nav_titles)` will get you a `MenuItem`, then calling `getItemId()` on it will get you the id of the item, which is `int`

Comment: please try the updated code above, it's just a matter of assigning the right variable

Comment: mDefaultFrag is a MenuItem. switchFragment takes MenuItems, and then the switch statement within it gets the item id

Comment: Yeah then the above code should work fine for you :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I still get an error: 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.view.MenuItem.getItemId()' on a null object reference'. This is caused where I call switchFragment(mDefaultFrag) in my onCreate method to run the default fragment. If I run it with debug, I can see that mDefaultFrag is null. I've tried putting the call in both onCreate and onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: You should not put it in`onCreate()`. Does it still give you `NullPointerExeption` if you **only** put it in `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean, I've tried it in both (not simultaneously). Same error both times.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you have now please? Something weird is going on..

Comment: Also the xml for your menu

Comment: Done. I think the problem is that onCreateOptionsMenu does exactly that - creates the options menu, not a navigation drawer.

Comment: Change `R.menu.menu_main` to `R.menu.nav` in your `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: You are not inflating the correct menu here, your menu xml is `nav.xml`, so you need to inflate `R.menu.nav`

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to go, because if I remove any standalone call to `switchFragment` it all works perfectly - the nav drawer works fine, display its options, and switches fragments, all without anything other than the default code in onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: I've just been doing exactly that - great minds think alike :)

Answer (score 0):

**Implementation of Navigation drawer with MenuItems.**

this is a working sample. you can update it as whatever you want.

Create activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

then create app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.root5solutions.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

then create nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

then create a menu xml and name it as activity_main_drawer in res-> menu -> activity_main_drawer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>

    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>

    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

in your MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image]